# How to use AppleScript in a bash script to create an alias for an app?

Tags: terminal, applescript, bash, script, alias

I need to create an alias on my Desktop to an app in my Applications folder, using a bash script file.

As far as I know, it's only possible with AppleScript.
Unfortunately, my AppleScript skills are non-existent. 
I couldn't find a good *working* example on how to create an alias on my Desktop.

1) How do I create an alias on my Desktop using AppleScript?

2) How do I insert this AppleScript into my bash script file so that it could work in Terminal?

Comment: Did Apple not release a new version of that AppleScript editor which would observe your actions and make AppleScripts for you?  Even if you needed to tweak them afterwards, such a thing was helpful for me when I was first learning AppleScript in the OS 7 era.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`osascript` will run AppleScript code in your shell. This example uses a HEREDOC to present the code to `osascript`.

```
/usr/bin/osascript <<'EOF'
tell application "Finder"
    set myapp to POSIX file "/Applications/Chess.app" as alias
    make new alias to myapp at Desktop
    set name of result to "Chess.app"
end tell
EOF
```

Source- [Link](http://www.jamf.com/jamf-nation/discussions/14563/create-alias-through-the-terminal-with-a-custom-filename)

Answer (score 4):

Why not skip the Applescript and just create a **symbolic link** in bash?  It behaves exactly like an alias on the desktop except now you can work with it in bash.    See this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/240552/119271) for a breakdown of aliases, hard links and sym links.

So, your command would be:

`ln -s /path/to/application/MyApp.app /Users/username/Desktop/MyApp`

Where MyApp.app and username is the name of the application and the user respectively.

Comment: because symbolic links don't keep track of the linked to file if it moves?

Comment: because symbolic links in /Applications don't show up in Spotlight (⌘-Space) but aliases do