# How can I create a Finder alias in a bash script that reads arguments from the command-line?

Tags: terminal, finder, bash, automation, alias

I'd like to write a bash script that takes 2 inputs:

1. path to actual file
2. path of a Finder alias file (not a unix link) to be created that refers to 1.

The bash script should pass these inputs to an automation script that creates the alias.

I've seen [How to use AppleScript in a bash script to create an alias for an app?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/278117/how-to-use-applescript-in-a-bash-script-to-create-an-alias-for-an-app) but I have not been able to adapt it for my goal.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With minimal error handling:

```
#!/bin/sh

[ -f "$1" ] || exit 1
[ "$2" ] || exit 1

alias=$(basename "$2")

/usr/bin/osascript <<EOF
tell application "Finder"
    set myapp to POSIX file "$1" as alias
    make new alias to myapp at Desktop
    set name of result to "$alias"
end tell
EOF

mv ~/Desktop/"$alias" "$2"
```