# Can't navigate to folder alias on server in the save window

Tags: macos, alias

After upgrading to macOS High Sierra, I can't save a file to the alias of a folder in the open/save dialog box on a server.

When browsing to the folder I want to save the file to, the folder aliases are greyed out, this problem doesn't occur on previous versions of macOS or when the folder alias isn't located on a server.

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: I personally don't like using the Finder aliases; instead I use symlinks that I create in Terminal.  See this for more info:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/240542/cant-cd-into-alias/240552#240552

Answer (score 2):

Did anyone find a solution to this? This sounds like the same basic problem we've been having since upgrading to Monterey, but we skipped several versions in between.

In addition to aliases being grayed out from app Save/Open dialogs, they also function improperly in the Finder. Instead of acting as a pointer, it acts as a file. Eg, an alias to a folder needs to be double-clicked to open it (which then jumps back to the original file path, so it does no good as an alias for navigation purposes). An alias to a file acts as a file type; eg, an image in a layout linked to an alias won't work because it reads as a non-image file.

Aliases in the server environment have become essentially worthless with this upgrade. They still function as always on the local desktop, however.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/322134)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and haven't found an answer yet.

The Problem: aliases and symlinks on the server are disabled in file dialogs for apps running from clients. Sole exception I've found is Apple's TextEdit on client, which can navigate through aliases that are on the server (with file dialog for open but not for save). Every other app, apple and otherwise, that I've tried on clients, including latest Apple Pages (version 7.1 (5683)) and Safari (Version 11.1.2 (13605.3.8)), find aliases on the server to be greyed out and disabled in file dialog windows, for both open and save. Aliases on the server work fine when double-clicked in Finder by clients.

This happens on server running macOS Sierra (10.12.6) with Server.app 5.3.1, and on server running macOS High Sierra (10.13.6) with Server.app 5.6.1.

Client macs are all running macOS High Sierra (10.13.6).

Things that work:

- An alias that is ON the client can point to a file on the server: apps on the client such as pages can use that alias in a file dialog to get to the remote folder.
- An alias that is on the server can be used in file dialogs by apps on the server.

My tests so far:

- From client mac, make alias on the server for a folder on the server. Pages and Safari on client find that alias grey (unusable) in file dialog.
- On server, make alias on the server for a folder on the server. Safari on server can follow the alias (which appears active, not grey) in a file dialog. Safari on a client can NOT follow the alias, which appears grey and unusable in file dialog.