# Finder shortcut in doc not showing all subfolders (in list view)

Tags: macos, finder, dock

I'm getting used to my new Mac... I created a shortcut to a folder that I placed next to the bin icon, to allow me quick access to frequently used folders. It contains about 700 subfolders named by our client's names.

In list view, it only shows subfolders starting with the letter 'M' and won't go further than that. In grid view, I can view all subfolders.

Obviously, navigating such a list would be much more effective in list view.

Any ideas why such a limitation in list view?

Comment: What version of macOS?  How did you create the “shortcut”? Is it a Finder Alias?  Maybe a [Symbolic Link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/240552/119271) might work better.

Comment: I added a folder of 3,400 items to the Dock and can confirm that there do seem to be size limits on List view, but not on Grid view.  Grid view is, of course, almost impossible to use as it takes forever to display all the icons!  The List view behaviour is odd. Alternative: Add the folder to Finder's Sidebar.